# Unable to import 'django.db' pylint (import-error)

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

A friend and I are collaborating on a Django project. After he created the repository, I did a git pull and opened the code in Visual Studio Code. However, when I attempt to import any libraries I get this error

[image: this error]

with the error code Unable to import 'django.db' pylint (import-error). Can someone help in fixing this error please?

Comment: Looks like you are not using the correct virtual environment for `pylint`.

Comment: I started a virtual environment using "pipenv shell" and installed django in the environment. Is it possible that the error could be because my friend started the project on his machine and me pulling it from git causes the error?